# INSERT INTO EXCEPT using only 2 identify columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, sql-server-2012, insert

hopefully this is an easy one for you folk smarter than me. I am trying to perform an insert into a table from another matching table, but I only want to insert if the row doesn't already exist. Some of these values in the row if it exists may be changed. Which is okay.

I'm thinking if two of the columns match upon insert, then don't insert and leave record as is. If those two columns don't match then insert the row. I have looked through merge, and also INSERT INTO EXCEPT. This code will work: but it is not what I need.

```
INSERT INTO LotDetail
SELECT UID, LotKey, SerialNo, TypeID, HotWeight, YieldGradKey, PeltGrade, 
WeightRange, MarketValue, PremiumDiscount, PeltValue, OffalValue, 
PricingKey, USDAGrade, [Timestamp] FROM LotDetail
EXCEPT
SELECT UID, LotKey, SerialNo, TypeID, HotWeight, YieldGradKey, PeltGrade, 
WeightRange, MarketValue, PremiumDiscount, PeltValue, OffalValue, 
PricingKey, USDAGrade, [Timestamp] FROM LotDetail_STAGING
```

The problem with the above code is that I must match all columns otherwise it tells me the table definition doesn't match. I only want to timestamp and serialno as the identifiers. I don't want to match on the other fields as they may change.

The problem is that if the record exists on the LotDetail table already and the 'hotweight' or 'marketvalue' have changed, I want to preserve those changes and not overwrite the record. I am simply looking to insert ONLY when 'serialno' and 'timestamp' don't exist. Those fields cannot be changed. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, I think you have your tables backwards.  It makes more sense to me to insert from the "staging" table into the final table.

Then, you can use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `EXCEPT`:

```
INSERT INTO LotDetail(UID, LotKey, SerialNo, TypeID, HotWeight, YieldGradKey, PeltGrade, 
                      WeightRange, MarketValue, PremiumDiscount, PeltValue, OffalValue, 
                      PricingKey, USDAGrade, [Timestamp]
                     )
    SELECT UID, LotKey, SerialNo, TypeID, HotWeight, YieldGradKey, PeltGrade, 
           WeightRange, MarketValue, PremiumDiscount, PeltValue, OffalValue, 
           PricingKey, USDAGrade, [Timestamp]
    FROM LotDetail_STAGING ls
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM LotDetail l
                      WHERE l.SerialNo = ls.serialNo AND
                            l.[Timestamp] = ls.[Timestamp]
                     );
```

I also think it is a good idea to list the columns when doing an `INSERT`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I needed. It tests perfect.